# What is the type of chip commonly used in android device as internal memory?

Tags: flash, android

What is the type of chip commonly used in android device as internal memory? Where the operating system resides, and often show up as sdcard0 (correct me if I'm wrong)?

Comment: Currently the device of choice should be mostly emmc, NAND flash, and UFS. Technically they are all NAND flash based devices, but sometimes NAND flash without an integrated controller is used directly, aka raw NAND. (https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown seems has a lot if info on the components, e.g. Galaxy S5 uses eMMC, but S6 switched to UFS, so does Pixel XL, but iphone 6 seems to be using raw NAND)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the phone. They started using NAND, raw flash accessed directly. Then they moved to eMMC, NAND with an embedded controller for better performance. Recently, many have moved to newwer generation technology like Samsung UFS http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/products/flash-storage/ufs/

Specifically, none of these are a type of EEPROM, a specific type of memory technology, that has no where near the memory density of NAND.